# ASP.NET JavaScript popup window failing at getting a property

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my ASP.NET application, my popup window is returning null for a specific variable. 
When I click a button this JavaScript gets fired:

```
function Picker_OrderDefaultFirst() {
    OpenPageWithParam('OrderPermanentItems', '?ID=' + "<%=CommitteeUId %>" + "&btn=1", returnOrderPicker);
    return false;
}
```

`returnOrderPicker` looks like:

```
function returnOrderPicker() {
    alert("Test fra returnOrderPicker");
}
```

`OpenPageWithParam` looks like:

```
function OpenPageWithParam(PageName, Query, ReturnFunction) {
    var _window = null;

    InitBlocker();

    switch (PageName) {

        case "OrderPermanentItems":
            _window = PopupCenter(ROOT_DIR + "/Forms/Pickers/PermanentItemsPicker.aspx" + Query, PageName, 590, 600);
            break;
    }

    _window.ReturnFunction = ReturnFunction;

    return _window;
}
```

I'm setting the popup window's property `ReturnFunction` to be `ReturnFunction` of data from previous page. (In this example `returnOrderPicker` Function).

But, when window pops up, the value of `window.ReturnValue` is `undefined`.

Calling in popup window looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = function (sender, eventArgs) { alert(window.ReturnFunction + " Window PermanentItemPickerPopup "); }
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is window.ReturnValue ?

Comment: if i   alert("popup.js = " + _window.ReturnFunction); in openpagewithparam, it returns right value

Comment: `I'm setting the popup window's property ReturnFunction to be ReturnFunction of data from previous page.` Does this mean you are somehow trying to set the popup vars in the previous page and then call it on the next page?

Comment: no, i sending parameter from a page to popup page, is it not possible?